# What is the difference between: Chandrashekhar limit and Schwarzchild radius?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, event-horizon, stellar-physics

I want a qualitative difference between the [Chandrashekhar limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrasekhar_limit) and [Schwarzchild radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius). They both pretty much look like the same thing.

Comment: Proof of your work on the distinction ? What's your understanding so far ?

Comment: One is mass and the other one is radius? :P

Comment: So far I know that the schwarzchild radius is the size to which when a body is reduced to, the esacpe velocity is equal to the speed of light(the mass of the body remaining constant ).I also know that the Chandrashekhar limit is the mass at which a body will collapse under its own gravitational pull.But both practically deal with the same thing.Both deal with the density of the body.So what exactly is the difference between them that we need to classify them as two different concepts?

Comment: The two are completely different. The Chandrashekhar limit is a quantum mechanical effect and the Schwarzschild radius is a general relativistic effect. They have nothing in common.

Comment: I down-voted for lack of effort and I rarely downvote.  Even the first lines of the wikipedia pages would tell you they're different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key difference (other than the fact that one is a radius limit and the other a mass limit) is that the Schwarzschild limit is when the gravity is so strong that *no* force can oppose it, but the Chandrasekhar limit is when the gravity is so strong that only one *specific* force, the gas pressure of degenerate electrons, cannot oppose it.  Also, as pointed out above, the former is a limit on the radius for a *given* mass, for any forces, whereas the latter is a limit on the mass itself, applying only when the electrons are degenerate.  The connection is that the Schwarzschild limit says how much you can compress a *given mass* before no force could oppose gravity, whereas the Chandrasekhar limit says how much mass you need such that the self-gravity, given a long enough time of losing heat, will always contract within the Schwarzschild limit for that mass.  Any mass above the Chandra limit will eventually contract below its Schwarzschild limit, but a lesser mass might not contract below its Schwarzschild limit, ever.   Also, a mass much larger than the Chandrasekhar limit can contract below its Schwarzschild radius without ever becoming degenerate, so would collapse even if there was no such thing as degeneracy or the Chandra limit.

Answer (score 1):

The Schwarzschild radius (sometimes historically referred to as the gravitational radius) is the radius of a sphere such that, if all the mass of an object were to be compressed within that sphere, the escape velocity from the surface of the sphere would equal the speed of light.

White dwarfs resist gravitational collapse primarily through electron degeneracy pressure. (By comparison, main sequence stars resist collapse through thermal pressure.) The Chandrasekhar limit is the mass above which electron degeneracy pressure in the star's core is insufficient to balance the star's own gravitational self-attraction. Consequently, white dwarfs with masses greater than the limit would be subject to further gravitational collapse, evolving into a different type of stellar remnant, such as a neutron star or black hole.

Comment: Not correct that a white-dwarf star that undergoes gravitational collapse will leave a neutron star or black hole, they generally don't.   That requires a larger star that (I think) goes nova before it reaches the white dwarf stage, but I'm not 100% certain there.   Mostly, maybe always, the Chandrasekhar limit supernova leaves no remnant.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrasekhar_limit

Comment: The issue there is what the white dwarf is made of.  Most white dwarfs are mostly carbon, so when they collapse, the carbon undergoes runaway fusion, and that's why there's no remnant-- they explode (type Ia supernovae).  If the white dwarf is mostly iron, which can also happen  when it is not really a white dwarf but instead exists as the core of a more massive star (core collapse supernovae), it will not undergo runaway fusion so it will leave a remnant.